# Facebook SDK samples errors

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I followed the steps for importing the samples from Facebook SDK 3.5.2 in Eclipse
( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/ )
but still get error when I try to run any of them.

When I right-click on Scrumptious, SessionLoginSample or the other samples, I get this error.

> [2013-11-14 15:03:42 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
>
> [2013-11-14 15:03:42 - SessionLoginSample] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.

The Facebook SDK is connected right to the samples, its green and correct.
It also says "**your project contains errors, please fix them before running your application**"

The thing is, there is no error, no red dots or anything, just imported them, made an clean on the project, no errors, and still, it wont work.

I know that Facebook dont update there example codes, tutorial codes or the samples even if they update the SDK, so what can the problem be? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I also don't know what is causing this, but when I updated the build target to atleast android 4.1.2, it worked.

To do this, change `target` to atleast `android-16`

Or you can right-click the project name on the explorer, select `Android` on the left pane and choose atleast `android 4.1.2` as your project build target.